# Installed Ubuntu 14.04 now can't boot windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I installed Ubuntu so that I could still dual boot and run Windows 10 when I needed to but whenever I try to run any of the windows boot options from the grub menu I just get an error message and something along the lines of `can't find disk image`.

I ran Boot-Repair and got [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13461981/). It added a few items to the grub menu, but I still can't boot Windows.

My computer is a Lenovo u310 which came with windows 8 pre-installed and I later updated it to Windows 10. It has a dual hard drive system (it came like that) with a 500GB HDD and a 32GB SSD. I seem to remember that by default some of the boot files are on the SSD and I suspect that this may be where the problem lies, as the Ubuntu installer assumes you have only one hard drive.

As you'll see, that paste files is from a few months ago and after failing to get back into Windows at the time I just left it as it wasn't urgent at the time. It is now pretty urgent.

I just tried to boot windows from a USB by installing the Windows 10 iso on a USB stick using GParted and and UNetbootin. I was going to try to use the Repair Windows option, however I can't seem to boot from the USB. I tried adding an option to do so in Grub using Grub Customizer, but when I try to use that option it says the Secure Boot is not allowing it to do so, and I am not allowed to disable Secure Boot in the system setup menu. I seem to remember that can be done in Windows, but I don't know how else to do it.

Comment: You can disable secure boot from BIOS and it is usually advised to do so before installing Ubuntu. Moreover, I recently installed the same OSes on a machine and interestingly enough they both were working when my boot priority was EFI instead of Legacy.

Comment: You have Intel SRT which is seen as RAID. It used to be that Ubuntu Desktop would not install at all, then only grub does not install. If primarily Windows user turn SRT off, fix grub, then turn SRT back on. If primarily Ubuntu and 32GB which only the amount of RAM is actually used by SRT, you can erase it (Windows will be slower booting) and install Ubuntu's / (root) to SSD making it fast. Have /home on HDD.  lenovo u310  - install Ubuntu to part of SSD Post #19 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2129157

Comment: Jay T, the point is that I cannot turn off secure boot in the BIOS. It won't allow me to change the selection from enabled. I did turn it off before installing Ubuntu but it now seems to be back on and won't let me turn it off.

Comment: oldfred how do I turn SRT off?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with Super GRUB 2 disk.

You can download it from [here](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/).

Then install it in a USB using [Unetbootin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/) Now you could restart your system and make sure it is set in the boot option menu.

Comment: Seems like a good idea but until I can turn off secure boot and boot from the usb then I can't do this (as I wrote above, I am not able to disable secure boot in the BIOS)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're running into this bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1091464

The three easiest solutions are:

- **Disable Secure Boot** -- I know you said in a comment that you can't do this, but you might want to try again. Resetting your firmware to its defaults may clear away whatever is preventing this change; however, this runs the risk of removing the reference to Ubuntu's boot manager in the NVRAM, which would then require additional repairs.
- **Install rEFInd** -- My [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) is known to work around the problem. (rEFInd is more reliable at launching Windows than is GRUB.) If you install rEFInd from Ubuntu, it should copy Shim and work with Secure Boot enabled, with the caveat that you'll need to enroll `refind.cer` and/or `refind_local.cer` from the `EFI/refind/keys` directory on the ESP when you reboot. This is not hard if you know it's coming, but may cause panic if you don't expect it. See the [rEFInd Secure Boot documentation](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/secureboot.html) for much more on this topic.
- **Use the computer's built-in boot manager** -- Most EFI-based computers have an ugly and awkward but built-in boot manager. You typically access it by hitting Esc, Enter, or a function key (usually F8 or higher) soon after turning on the computer (before GRUB, rEFInd, or anything else appears). This tool should enable you to boot to Windows, but on some computers it is so limited or difficult to access that it's next to useless.